# how to stop a timer with an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, timer

I'm trying to stop a timer that ticks down from ten seconds to zero.
The problem is that the finish method only returns the first tick, rather than counting all the numbers down to one.
How can I make a boolean method return a value for every second rather than just the first?

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Countdown {
    static int interval;
    static Timer timer;
    boolean  off;
    public Countdown() {

        int seconds = 10;
        int delay = 1000;
        int period = 1000;
        timer = new Timer();

        interval = seconds;

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                System.out.println(setInterval());

            }
        }, delay, period);
    }

    private int setInterval() {
        off = false;
        if (interval == 1){
            timer.cancel();
            off = true;

            return --interval;
        }else{
            off = false;
            return --interval;

        }       
    }

    public boolean finish(){

        return off;
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public static void main(String[] args){

    Countdown countDown = new Countdown();
    countDown.finish()

    System.out.println(countDown.finish);

    if(countDown.finish() == true){
        System.out.println("works");
    }


}
```

Comment: You need to wait for it to finish.  BTW You are writing a lot of code which would be better handled by a newer library `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the value of `finish` every second, you should design your code to print it ever second, not just on startup...

ATM `finish` is only printed in the main-method and nowhere else. Move that line into the `Runnable` used by the `Timer` and it should print as expected.